# Is "rare anomalies" correct to use?

Tags: american-english

Does it sound too redundant to use "Rare anomalies" in a sentence to describe a rare occurance?

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it be? What does the dictionary tell you about *rare* and *anomaly*? How is this different from *yellow butterfly*?

Comment: So you think "rare anomalies" is strange but use "too redundant". Hilarious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anomaly simply means

> something that deviates from what is standard, normal, or expected: *there are a number of anomalies in the present system*

It does not encompass the connotation of rare, just something that deviates from what is standard. Hence, it is alright to use 'rare anomalies'. Or, if you don't feel comfortable, you could just use another phrase like 'rare occurrence'.

Comment: To support Ronald answer, "rare anomalies" is not a pleonasm and unfortunately "frequent anomalies" often occur;

Comment: If you were speaking about software, "frequent anomalies" would mean "this is seriously buggy and acts weird a lot"; "rare anomalies" would mean "every once in a while it does something strange" - so that usage seems reasonable.

Comment: Great point! A simple point to prove that, well, just take a look at any stock market graph. General increase or decrease, but plenty of anomalies indeed.

Comment: @Graffito Thanks for the clarification. Frequent rare anomalies often occur most of the time. hehehe... j/k

Comment: @JoeMcMahon I actually was referring to buggy software code in an email I was typing up when the "Rare anomalies" came up that was somewhat of an eye soar for me.... just wanted to double check before sending out the email. Thanks.